# Can't display 2 partials on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m trying to do the "simple todo list" task, but I don’t know how to display it on one page as on screenshot http://joxi.net/v29DKEVcBLB5mG (that is, there is a list of saved items and to the right is a form for adding a new one). If everything is separate it works for me, but when it renders 2 partial on one page - error `undefined method each for #<Track:0x00007f8fc42c2698> (NoMethodError in Tracks#new)`
Here is my new.html.erb

```
<h1> Create a New Item!</h1>
<%= render 'table' %>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Table partial:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>All Tracks</th>
      <th>It's description</th>
      <th>Priority</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Restore</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @track.each do |track| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= track.id %> </td>
      <td> <%= link_to track.item, edit_track_path(track.id) %> </td>
      <td> <%= track.description %> </td>
      <td> <%= track.priority %> </td>
      <td> <%= track.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %> </td>
      <td><%= button_to "Delete", track_path(track.id), method: :delete %></td>
      <td><%= button_to "Restore", track_path(track.id), method: :put %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And _form partial:

```
  <%= form_for @track do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :item %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :item %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.select :priority, priorities,
        prompt: "Select priority" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', tracks_path %>
    <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
```

And Tracks controller:

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_track, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @track = Track.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @track = Track.new
  end

  def create
    @track = Track.new(track_params)
    if @track.save
      flash[:success] = "It works!"
      redirect_to tracks_path
    else
      flash[:success] = "Its wrong!"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @track.update(track_params)
      redirect_to @track
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @track.destroy
    redirect_to tracks_path
  end

private
  def track_params
    params.require(:track).permit(:item, :description, :priority)
  end

  def find_track
    @track = Track.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@track` is a single `Track` object. Do you also set `@tracks`? If so change your table view to `@tracks.each do`.

Comment: Add TracksController to the question, please

Comment: @Vasilisa just added

Comment: engineersmnky No, I don't. I added my controller's code to post, actually if I set @tracks the same error still appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you render the page for Tracks#new action it should be

```
def new
  @tracks = Track.all
  @track = Track.new
end
```

and

```
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
```

in view iterator. Also you need to add `@tracks = Track.all` to the `create` action, otherwise you will not be able render tracks table on validation error.

Note, by convention we use plural from for collections and single for single record. You need to have both `@tracks` and `@track` in the `new` action since you want to render all pages and create a new one.

Btw, do you use `index` action anywhere? If no, you can safely remove it from controller and `routes.rb`

Comment: @KevinLingard, happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

In controller try to use **@tracks** for multiple records.

```
  def index
    @tracks = Track.all
  end
```

In Table partial use the below

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>All Tracks</th>
      <th>It's description</th>
      <th>Priority</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Restore</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @tracks.each do |track| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= track.id %> </td>
      <td> <%= link_to track.item, edit_track_path(track.id) %> </td>
      <td> <%= track.description %> </td>
      <td> <%= track.priority %> </td>
      <td> <%= track.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %> </td>
      <td><%= button_to "Delete", track_path(track.id), method: :delete %></td>
      <td><%= button_to "Restore", track_path(track.id), method: :put %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You have used @track for single and multiple records. Try to use it **@tracks** for multiple records and **@track** for single object.

Comment: The same error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass NoMethodError in Tracks#new)